# Animate UITableViewCells with repeat and scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitableview

I have a simple table view, I'm using custom cells with one `UIImage` and some labels.

I want to animate the image size, for that I've added the following in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

        NotificationTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[NotificationTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

if( [[[notification objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] valueForKey:@"readed"] isEqualToString:@"readed"])
    {   

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9
                              delay:0.3
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState |  UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                         animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{
                             cell.imgIcon.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             cell.imgIcon.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                         }];
    }
    return cell;
    }
```

When I launch the app it works ok, only the "readed" cells are animating in a bucle with the  UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat option.

The problem begins when i scroll over the tableview. Some "readed" cells stops animating, and the cells animation time loop is different in each cell.

Any idea?

Thanks

EDITED: I think that the problem is something about reusable cells.

Answer (score 0):

You said "I try reloadind the tableview but this dont work." (sic)

You tried reloading the table view when and how? In response to a 
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification message handler being called? Post that code.

I would add a log statement in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method to make sure it's being called, and log the indexPath(s) that are being updated.

Are you sure you want the images in every cell of your table view to animate every time your app comes back to the foreground. That seems like it would be annoying.

Comment: I'm really just throwing animation if the notification is not readed .

Comment: That doesn't clarify your question at all.

Comment: Im reloading the tableView when the app becomes active.[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

Comment: The method cellForRowAtIndexPath it's being called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the tableView should cause the animation to occur, as Duncan has said. Make sure you breakpoint/log the animation to make sure that the code is actually getting there. Once you figure out how to cause the animation to occur again by reloading the table, you can add two NSNotificationCenter callouts to let the app know to reload the table once the app resumes activity from the background.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

Just set up the proper selectors to handle and reload your table:

e.g

```
- (void)appDidBecomeActive:(id)sender {
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying . I throw  [_tableView reloadData] when the app becomes active.